# Json Deserialise return null when convert to list of object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialise the json into custom class list using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Here is my code:

```
public List<EmployeeModel> getEmployee()
{
    string Baseurl = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //Passing service base url  
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        //Define request data format  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  

        var EmpResponse = new List<EmployeeModel>();
        var Res = client.GetAsync("employees");

        Res.Wait();
        var result = Res.Result;
        //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
            var r = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


            EmpResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeModel>>(r);

            //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
        }
        //returning the employee list to view  
        return EmpResponse;
    }
}
```

When I check the variable r value I am getting following Json String:

```
[
    {
        "id": "317",
        "employee_name": "Nitza",
        "employee_salary": "775",
        "employee_age": "1",
        "profile_image": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "318",
        "employee_name": "Nitza Ivri",
        "employee_salary": "10000",
        "employee_age": "33",
        "profile_image": ""
    }
]
```

Also, my model code is as per below:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string id { get; private set; }
    public string employee_name { get; private set; }
    public string employee_salary { get; private set; }
    public string employee_age { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: *Please* don't call 'Wait()` and `.Result` on asynchronous operations! HttpClient methods are async for a reason, not because someone forgot to add blocking methods. Change `List<EmployeeModel>  getEmployee()` to `async Task<List<EmployeeModel>> getEmployee()` instead and use `await`. Let the caller decide whether to block (bad) or keep working asynchronously

Comment: As for the actual problem, by making the setters private you *prevent* JSON.NET from setting any values

Comment: Is there a reason the properties in the model are a private 'set'?

Comment: Even with private setters, the duplicate shows that the `JsonProperty` attribute will allow Json.NET to use them

Comment: @JamesS - Yes, private because preventing set value of property outside of the class

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers If that's the case, how do you expect to populate it in this method?

Comment: as per @PanagiotisKanavos, I set property as JsonProperty with Private access modifier. It was my silly mistake that i used private in set and setting value in method. so, I think using JsonProperty is better solution rather than make it public, isn't it? are they both same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that your properties in EmployeeModel has private set. You need to remove private from your properties then it would be able to deserialize successfully. Your entity should be like following:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string employee_name { get; set; }
    public string employee_salary { get; set; }
    public string employee_age { get; set; }
}
```

Also, your `EmployeeModel` does not contain property `profile_image`. You need to add this property to your model.

If it is important for you to keep your properties setters as private, you can provide a constructor that has parameters like:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public EmployeeModel(string id, string employee_name,string employee_salary, string employee_age, string profile_image )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.employee_name = employee_name;
        this.employee_salary = employee_salary;
        this.employee_age = employee_age;
        this.profile_image = profile_image;
    }

    public string id { get; private set; }
    public string employee_name { get; private set; }
    public string employee_salary { get; private set; }
    public string employee_age { get; private set; }
    public string profile_image { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: property is set as private because not body can set the value of property outside of the class

Comment: Please see updated